# Angular smart (container) / dumb (presentational) component architecture, conditional logic, and propagating inputs

Tags: angular, architecture

Consider two dumb components, A and B. One of either A **OR** B will be shown by component C, which is used in smart component D.

```
  D (smart)
  |
  C (dumb)
 / \
A   B (both dumb)
```

A and B both have 10 inputs each. I see at least a few ways to handle this:

1. Have C take the 20 inputs that would be the union of the inputs of components A and B, even though I only ever use half of those inputs
2. Make C a smart component, but that would mean a lot more smart components in a real-world complex application where this pattern occurs in lots of places
3. "Project down" the A and B components by having C take a TemplateRef or similar, and then only bind the inputs in D and have D decide which to show
4. Try to combine parts of the inputs into larger "input objects". It seems like this would complicate data binding since A and B would only be notified that the "input object" changed and wouldn't know the specifics of what changed, unless I had differ logic inside those components.

Is there a best practice or a common practice of handling this situation? An analogous problem arises for the outputs of A and B, and both situations come up when using any two-way data binding!

I have tried searching all around and even tried looking for recommendations for React instead of Angular, but to no avail.

I can try to produce some example code similar to the code I'm working on if that would be helpful, but it would take some time.

Comment: If A and B are supposed to be dumb, why would they need a differ to know what has changed? Make them really dumb: they take a few inputs, and they display these few inputs. 10 inputs looks like an awful lot to me.

Comment: Another option is to use routing instead of child components for A and B.

Comment: Maybe make C slightly less dumb and instead of seperate inputs use viewChildren to get refs to A and B and set data using component (C).? It’s tricky, but at least you don’t need loads of inputs inside the template..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd give strong consideration to moving the data communication to a shared service, instead of trying to pass all of that through Inputs and Outputs.

If Component "C" doesn't need any of the information bound for "A" or "B", then it shouldn't have to handle it at all.

The shared service could have the 20 or so data items, as well as Subject or BehaviorSubject for "A" and "B" to communicate changes back to "D".

I'm not sure if what you're doing is complex enough to warrant it, but if you're doing lots of stuff like this, then Redux can give you a nice pattern for this.

I've started to use Redux a bit lately, to great success, when simple binding is too simple. I found ngrx/store a bit fussy, difficult to use and not well documented, despite it getting a lot of press, and found angular-redux (a thin Angular wrapper over the actual Redux library) to be easier to use, and it has better documentation.